# Structured data is not picked up in Google's rich result testing tool, but works in schema.org

Tags: seo, google-rich-snippets, structured-data

I'm running into a problem when implementing structured data.

I am simply trying to display the website name **Evolve Finance** in SERP’s rather than the URL **evolvefinance.co.uk**

Here is examples of my Google SERPs **site:https://www.evolvefinance.co.uk**

When validating **https://www.evolvefinance.co.uk** with **validator.schema.org** I am getting **0 Errors and 0 Warnings**.

But when using Google's rich testing tool, **the result is No Items Detected**.

When I check the crawled page in Google Search Console the schema.org is visible but Google’s bot does not seem to be reading the contents of the script tag.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context" : "https://schema.org",
      "@type" : "WebSite",
      "name" : "Evolve Finance",
      "url" : "https://www.evolvefinance.co.uk/"
    }
</script>
```

I'm in the dark why Google's bot is not detecting the contents of the schema.

Comment: That may help: https://www.sitelint.com/blog/google-rich-results-and-no-items-detected/

Answer (score 1):

> But when using Google's rich testing tool, the result is No Items
> Detected.

This tool only shows results for **[types supported by Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/search-gallery)**.
In your structured data, you are using the type `WebSite` which does not have Google's support for rich results. Also, your script has scarce content that can be skipped or ignored.

Things get a lot more complicated due to the fact that your content represents a financial business (Your Money Or Your Life - YMYL) that has no uniqueness in **[SERP](https://www.google.com/search?q=Evolve%20Finance)**:
[image]

The content of your website also does not represent comprehensive information about the business referred to in the content. Thus, yours lacks a uniquely identifiable entity that the name of the website representing that entity can be associated with.

Comment: The type `WebSite` is supported by Google and it's also referenced in the documentation as the preferred option to define the site name preference: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/site-names#how-site-names-in-google-search-are-created

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and, as mentioned by [Maniac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2950854/maniac) here

[Google Site Name showing url instead of structured data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78162985/google-site-name-showing-url-instead-of-structured-data)

adding the `potentialAction` entry to the structured data solved the validation issue for me:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context" : "https://schema.org",
      "@type" : "WebSite",
      "name" : "Evolve Finance",
      "url" : "https://www.evolvefinance.co.uk/",
      "potentialAction": {
        "@type": "SearchAction",
        "target": {
          "@type": "EntryPoint",
          "urlTemplate": ""https://www.evolvefinance.co.uk/?q={search_term_string}"
        },
        "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer is very much appreciated, I will give it a try tomorrow and let you know if it works for me.

Comment: Did you just add it to your home page or did you have to add it to all pages.

Comment: Yes, I'm currently adding this snippet to all the pages, but I'm not sure if that's necessary.

Comment: When I went to add the "potential action" snippet that you suggested I realised I already had that exact piece of code on my home page (and still do) and it has not worked for me.

Comment: I've been struggling with the same issue for the last few weeks. It seems like my issue in specific may be related to the website being relatively new, and it may take Google some time to be confident enough to show the website name in the Search results.