# Google Site Name showing url instead of structured data

Tags: json, seo, google-search, google-search-console

I am experiencing an issue when adding a [website](https://slowtraveljourney.com/en) to the **Google Search Console** .
The page is indexed correctly, and the title is set correctly in the `<head>`.

I've also added the structured data to the page as mentioned here:
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/site-names

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
[
  {
    "@context":"https://schema.org",
    "@type":"WebSite",
    "name":"<Site name>",
    "url":"<Site URL>",
    "alternateName":["Others"]
   }
]
</script>
```

But still, I cannot see the name of the site in the Google Search, only the website URL.
I tried to validate the schema using this:

https://search.google.com/test/rich-results

but structured data is not detected.
Using the schema validator, the tag is detected correctly:

https://validator.schema.org/

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: While the documentation doesn't state that the potentialAction property is explicitly required, it apparently doesn't work without it. Here is an example where I use the current structured data, adding only potentialAction:
https://i.imgur.com/vBaZvRs.png

Requires you to have search functionality. Additionally, the declared URL redirects to the same URL without the trailing slash. I would replace it with the final destination.

Comment: Thanks, now it's visible in the `Rich Results Test`! Now I'm waiting for the crawler to pick the change.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar issue with a client's site before.

As you mentioned, there can be conflicts between Google's and Schema.org's validator tools from time to time, often due to Google frequently updating its policies and merging schemas.

A useful workaround is to reference Google's [schema examples](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/search-gallery) directly from their documentation. Alternatively, changing the schema type (e.g., from 'Website' to 'Article' or 'Organization') can also be effective.